# Fancybox with YouTube movie in FireFox does not close entirely - see demo

Tags: jquery, firefox, youtube, fancybox

Window closes, but movie still plays in background.

When you close and recall fancy, you can see movie continuing to play.

See this link with demo (click on small YouTube icon):

http://reference.xarray.org.uk/pages.php/fancy-problem-jp-59

[edited: now link above behaves correctly - as problem was fixed - see: answer on the bottom]

Anyone knows how to remedy that?

Comment: it is happening in Firefox but not in chrome, strange!!

Comment: @Jeffz: See my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK .. after some research .. here it is.

Instead of calling swf object directly:

```
<a class="fancy_freehand" href="#myId" rel="fancybox" style="outline-style: none; text-decoration: none; "><img alt="" src="/images/user/jmvc_yt.png" /></a></p>
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="yEJw" style="width:auto; height:auto;">
    <object data="http://www.youtube.com/v/a2RA0vsZXf8?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;hd=1" height="576" id="close_player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1024">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/a2RA0vsZXf8?fs=1&amp;autoplay=1" />
      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
      <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    </object>
 </div>
</div>
```

... it is best to give credit to fancy box author(s) and do it his (their) way (note: 'iframe' class):

```
<a class="fancy_freehand iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a2RA0vsZXf8?autoplay=1"><img alt="" src="/images/user/jmvc_yt.png" /> </a>
```

It will make Chrome complaining about:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
```

but it is a minor side effect

tested in all recent versions of all browsers - IE:7,8,9

check same link (also works in FF):
http://reference.xarray.org.uk/pages.php/fancy-problem-jp-59

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in fancybox initialization script:

```
callbackOnClose: function() { 
    $("#fancy_content").empty(); 
}
```

**OR**

```
callbackOnClose: function() { 
    $("#fancy_content").html(" "); 
}
```

**Example 1:** `$("#fancy_content").empty();`

```
 $("a[rel=fancybox], .fancybox").fancybox({ 
  'overlayShow'     : false, 
  'zoomSpeedIn'     : 600, 
  'zoomSpeedOut'      : 500, 
  'easingIn'        : 'easeOutBack', 
  'easingOut'       : 'easeInBack', 
  callbackOnClose: function() { 
    $("#fancy_content").empty(); 
  } 
});
```

**Example 2:** `$("#fancy_content").html(" ");`

```
 $("a[rel=fancybox], .fancybox").fancybox({ 
  'overlayShow'     : false, 
  'zoomSpeedIn'     : 600, 
  'zoomSpeedOut'      : 500, 
  'easingIn'        : 'easeOutBack', 
  'easingOut'       : 'easeInBack', 
  callbackOnClose: function() { 
    $("#fancy_content").html(" "); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: sorry for slight delay - time zones an other duties --- html(), remove(), even detach() do not work really -- problem: you cannot bring back movie without reload, if you click on link again